# Why does jQuery .blur() freeze an element in firefox 8.0?

Tags: jquery, events, firefox, select, blur

```
$('.versionSelectWizardCoti').live('focus',function() {
    currentValSelect2 = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
    $(this).blur();
});
```

The `.blur()` call works in IE7+ and Chrome, but does not work in FF 8.0. The select element freezes and shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `$(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');` to `$(this).closest('your element class/id').attr('id');`

Comment: thanks john, but currentValSelect2 = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');  works fine, don't work the select element ( $('.versionSelectWizardCoti') ) after the .blur() event, this freeze the element and don't display the options